# AzureDevOps agentless jobs costs and limitations

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Is there any limitation to the number of allowed running agentless jobs?**

Context: We have an Azure Function task with await callback=true, the function is awaiting an approval from an external system. However we many have many pipelines awaiting approval at once.

I could not find this info on official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops

**Do agentless tasks cost/bill in anyway?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any limitation to the number of allowed running agentless
> jobs?

***No,*** no limitation for number.

But there has a limit on TSTUs. since there are no agents, the limitation is ***'Complex work item tracking queries create database load based on the number of work items they search through.'*** as mentioned in the below document. The TSTUs will grow up when running task 'queryWorkItems@0':

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#azure-devops-throughput-units-tstus

---

> Do agentless tasks cost/bill in anyway?

***Of course no cost on DevOps side(native DevOps).*** The tasks even not executed by any agent. It executed by the server itself.

A page to calculate the cost:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

Notice：above is only for native DevOps feature, DevOps has many extensions, that may be different. Anyway, cost is only the above. If not in it, there is no.